# Java JNA can't write float to memory

Tags: java, memory, floating-point, jna

I'm trying to write a float to memory but It's not working.

**Kernel32.java**

```
public abstract boolean WriteProcessMemory(Pointer paramPointer1, long paramLong, Pointer paramPointer2, int paramInt, IntByReference paramIntByReference);
```

**MemoryWriting.java**

```
public void writeMemory(int address, float[] data) {
    int size = data.length;

    Memory toWrite = new Memory(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        toWrite.setFloat(i, data[i]);
    }

    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(process, address, toWrite, size, null);
}
```

EDIT:

still same issue

```
public void writeMemory(int address, float[] data) {
    int size = data.length;

    Memory toWrite = new Memory(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        toWrite.setFloat(i * Float.SIZE / 8, data[i]);
    }

    kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(process, address, toWrite, size, null);
}
```

Comment: The `size` argument to `WriteProcessMemory` is the number of bytes to write, not the number of float elements.

Comment: explain? It worked just fine for writing bytes.

Comment: One float requires a buffer of size 4 bytes.  If you indicate the buffer is size "1", then only the first byte of the float will be read.  The `size` argument needs to be four times the number of float elements to be written.

Comment: so size = data.length * 4?

Comment: didnt work, same error

Comment: What do you expect, and what are you seeing?

Comment: I'm seeing the same size=1 offset = 4 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you make your own method signature that takes the `float[]` directly.

```
public interface MyKernel32 extends Kernel32 {
    MyKernel32 INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    void WriteProcessMemory(HANDLE hProcess, Pointer address, float[] data, int size, Pointer blah);
}
```

**EDIT**

You're writing float values at 1-byte increments.  A float is typically at least 4 bytes (`Float.SIZE / 8` bytes in Java), so you'd need to adjust your offset.  I *really* recommend using the function mapping, but if you insist in the extra overhead of copying the array to memory and then copying the memory buffer to process memory, you need to do this:

```
Memory m = ...;
float[] data = ...;
for(int i=0;i < data.length;i ++) {
    m.setFloat(i * Float.SIZE/8, data[i]);
}
```

Comment: so like this?

 public void writeMemory(int address, float[] data) {
  int size = data.length;

  Memory toWrite = new Memory(size);

  for (int i = 0; i < size / 8; i++) {
   toWrite.setFloat(i, data[i]);
  }

  kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(process, address, toWrite, size, null);
 }

Comment: I'm still getting same error as before even after the edit you posted.